# How do I query multiple sheets in Google Sheet that result in a single master sheet?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have multiple sheets, in the example, **Sheet1** and **Sheet2** that I would like to query that results in a single **Master sheet**. see the
[**Example sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SjAwgWHMhF3J_Q5y4z6dOgq1c5BRWop0Zo9bAYUCIC8/edit?usp=sharing)

I followed this [**tutorial**](https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-query-multiple-sheets/) but it seems like I am missing something as the **Master sheet** only show results from **Sheet1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Option 01 - with headers**

**Use this formula** or [***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1faxP2wm0yYT-HbuTfY50-zWjN4V2dhz48wPMnEsYN-E/copy) of the example sheet.

```
=QUERY({ Sheet1!A1:C;Sheet2!A2:C }, "Select * Where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]

**Explanation**

- `{}` Array
- `;`  Stack ranges on top of each other
- `,`  to join columns side by side *"we didn't need it in this example"*
- `"Select * Where Col1 is not null"` Select all columns where column1 is not empty

### **Option 02 - without headers**

```
=QUERY({ Sheet1!A2:C;Sheet2!A2:C }, "Select * Where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: `{ Sheet1!A1:C1;Sheet1!A2:C;Sheet2!A2:C }` can be reduced just to: `{ Sheet1!A1:C;Sheet2!A2:C }`

Comment: Much better this way, thanks